# Jquery UI dropdown behaving strangely on microsoft surface

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I have an application that uses jquery ui datepicker with the months and years shown as dropdowns. Across all devices and browsers, it seems to work fine...

Except, of course, on IE in Microsoft Surface (Pro 2).

The dropdowns seem to scroll in an infinite loop. On scrolling down from December, the scrollbar appears on the top again and starts scrolling from January. This behavior happens on the jquery UI website too. See attached screenshot.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hey @Snowman, did you ever find a solution to this? We are experiencing the same issue on a surface pro 4, IE 11

Comment: @DontFretBrett. I don't believe we did. Sorry bro.